# Writing Data in form of JSON from Flink to a file

Tags: java, json, apache-flink

When we were trying to write the processed JSON data from Flink into file using the method **writeAsCsv(path, writemode)**, the data as written into the file but we need to insert comma after every JSON which is not happening. We are using Apache Kafka as data source to Flink.

```
DataStream<Tuple5<String, String, String, String, String>> messageStream = env.addSource(new FlinkKafkaConsumer08<>(FLINK_TOPIC, new SimpleStringSchema(), properties)).flatMap(new StreamToTuple5()).keyBy(0);
String path = "/home/user/Documents/docs/csvfile/";
messageStream.writeAsCsv(path, FileSystem.WriteMode.OVERWRITE);
```

the output obtaining on executing this method is

```
{"temperSensorData":"28.489084691371364","temperSensorUnit":"celsius","timestamp":"1493270680759","timestamp2":"1493270680786","timestamp3":"1493270680787"}
{"temperSensorData":"28.489084691371467","temperSensorUnit":"celsius","timestamp":"1493270680761","timestamp2":"1493270680816","timestamp3":"1493270680816"}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve your problem by specifying `','` as your row delimiter:

```
messageStream.writeAsCsv(path, FileSystem.WriteMode.OVERWRITE, ",", ",")
```

Here the third argument is the row delimiter.